# Why am I getting a WARNING: Skipping key error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I use figaro and have a `config/application.yml` file. In it, I specify the development as such:

```
development:
  FACEBOOK_SECRET: '***'
  FACEBOOK_KEY: '***'
  PARSE_APP_ID: '***'
  PARSE_API_KEY: '***'
```

I use the [parse-ruby-client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client) gem to make push notifications to parse. It's configured in `config/initializers/parse.rb`

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

Parse.init :application_id => ENV['PARSE_APP_ID'],
           :api_key        => ENV['PARSE_API_KEY'],
           :quiet           => false
```

When I start my server or my sidekiq worker, I get this warning:

```
WARNING: Skipping key "PARSE_APP_ID". Already set in ENV.
WARNING: Skipping key "PARSE_API_KEY". Already set in ENV.
```

But I don't get that warning for the `FACEBOOK_SECRET` or `FACEBOOK_KEY`. Also, I read about the error and still don't quite understand.

How is `PARSE_APP_ID` and `PARSE_API_KEY` already set in ENV? When and where is this set?

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=warning%20skipping%20key%20already%20set%20in%20env&gws_rd=ssl) for "warning skipping key already set in env" does not tell me much. The first github link talks about how to remove the warning. I feel that if I set things up correctly, there should not be a warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what my problem is. I was setting the variables in my bash_profile. After I removed it and move it to application.yml, source ~/.bash_profile does not reset the ENV variable. You have to start a new shell.

Comment: In general, it means the variables already exist in ENV. You can always do `unset PARSE_APP_ID` and remove the environment variable.